# Loop Python Basic

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop

Running My Script has realized the need to store or retrieve `For` is a common variable for later use there for other purposes. If anyone knows how to store the resulting`print(link.get('href'))`in a common variable.

**Code:**

```
import requests


from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

Url='https://br.answers.search.yahoo.com/search?p=porque+escravizam+os+indios&guccounter=1&guce_referrer=aHR0cHM6Ly9ici5hbnN3ZXJzLnlhaG9vLmNvbS8&guce_referrer_sig=AQAAAJ667A0mUDEjLVx6pfks8w7FSsMqUwTnuRTXpDTkZoxPO9jjP-olDl37KqLbL0t-AG7H-7xs-rP4ddCp9NhDEAxBvSvSqmbx0L9EW2pLBKHJ1gyislcYuWHaHCijW1VunXB2Ih5o-47LSJRerSSxgWMosYe_rm6xWKQ3X2aJ_qPu'
r=requests.get(Url)


soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content,'html.parser')
for link in soup.select('h3 > a'):
    print(' \033[7;31;10mLINK \033[m')
    ***print(link.get('href'))***
```

Comment: Can't you just add it to a list?

Comment: It would have to be in its original state in the print command.

Comment: but also as it would be on a list

Comment: I deleted my answer because your question is unclear. What exactly do you need help with?

Comment: your answer is correct so I was doubtful what would call the print list (link.get ('href'))
I just needed an example of what I would call her in another 'for'.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by "It would have to be in its original state in the print command.". In general, it's a regular attribute, so you can access it as often as you want:

```py
import requests


from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

Url='https://br.answers.search.yahoo.com/search?p=porque+escravizam+os+indios&guccounter=1&guce_referrer=aHR0cHM6Ly9ici5hbnN3ZXJzLnlhaG9vLmNvbS8&guce_referrer_sig=AQAAAJ667A0mUDEjLVx6pfks8w7FSsMqUwTnuRTXpDTkZoxPO9jjP-olDl37KqLbL0t-AG7H-7xs-rP4ddCp9NhDEAxBvSvSqmbx0L9EW2pLBKHJ1gyislcYuWHaHCijW1VunXB2Ih5o-47LSJRerSSxgWMosYe_rm6xWKQ3X2aJ_qPu'
r=requests.get(Url)

all_links = []
soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content,'html.parser')
for link in soup.select('h3 > a'):
    print(' \033[7;31;10mLINK \033[m')
    print(link.get('href'))
    all_links.append(link.get('href'))
```